# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key. Must be [a-z0-9/._-]:

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, spigot

I'm making a plugin but when a start the server it gives this error massage

Error:

```
[16:43:41] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling CustomServer v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key. Must be [a-z0-9/._-]: Custom
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:220) ~[guava-31.1-jre.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.NamespacedKey.<init>(NamespacedKey.java:84) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.NamespacedKey.minecraft(NamespacedKey.java:175) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at me.entropire.customserver.CustomServer.onEnable(CustomEntropireServer.java:30) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:266) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:540) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:454) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:962) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:832) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-api-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:871) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.command.BukkitCommandWrapper.run(BukkitCommandWrapper.java:50) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:265) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.commands.CommandDispatcher.performCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:314) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.commands.CommandDispatcher.a(CommandDispatcher.java:298) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1960) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.network.PlayerConnection.lambda$18(PlayerConnection.java:1922) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.b(SourceFile:67) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.d(SourceFile:156) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.d(SourceFile:23) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1152) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.d(MinecraftServer.java:1) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.x(SourceFile:130) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.bg(MinecraftServer.java:1131) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1124) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.util.thread.IAsyncTaskHandler.c(SourceFile:139) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.p_(MinecraftServer.java:1108) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1019) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.20-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3797-Spigot-7e2af8b-091027a]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
```

Code:

```
package me.user.customserver;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryCloseEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class CoinBag implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void OnPlayerInterect(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();

        if (player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType() == Material.LEATHER_HORSE_ARMOR){
            if (player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getCustomModelData() == 1015) {
                ItemMeta meta = player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta();
                if (player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().hasLore()) {
                    String id = meta.getLore().toString();
                    id = id.replaceAll("C", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("i", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("o", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("n", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("b", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("a", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll("g", "");
                    id = id.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    String fileName = id + ".yml";
                        Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(player, 18, "CoinBag " + id);

                        File file = new File("plugins/CustomServer/" + fileName);
                        FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);

                        if (file.exists()){
                            ItemStack[] contents = ((List<ItemStack>) config.get("CoinBag.contents")).toArray(new ItemStack[0]);
                            inv.setContents(contents);
                        }
                    player.openInventory(inv);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    private void onPlayerExitInv(InventoryCloseEvent e) throws IOException {
        if (e.getView().getTitle().contains("CoinBag")){

            String name_inv = e.getView().getTitle();
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("C", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("i", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("o", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("n", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("B", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("a", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll("g", "");
            name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll(" ", "");
            ItemStack[] contants = e.getInventory().getContents();

            String fileName = name_inv + ".yml";

            File file = new File("plugins/CustomServer/" + fileName);
            FileConfiguration c = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(file);
            c.set("CoinBag.contents", contants);
            c.save(file);
        }
    }
}
```

the Error is because of this part of the code:

```
id = id.replaceAll(" ", "");
name_inv = name_inv.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

I have tried several ways to change special characters to nothing but the error does not go away.
and if i remove this part of code and then the error goas away but my code breaks.
can anyone tell me why this Error comes.

Comment: Use `custom` instead of `Custom`

Comment: witch Custom do i need to change?

Comment: You should set it as lower case (the namespace key on your onEnable)

Comment: it worked but now the items don't go in the inventory if a file is saved with the same Id

Answer (score 0):

This error info comes from here (NamespacedKey.java:84).

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(key != null && isValidKey(key), "Invalid key. Must be [a-z0-9/._-]: %s", key);
```

And there is a snippet of code that may be the reason.

```
private static boolean isValidKeyChar(char c) {
    return isValidNamespaceChar(c) || c == '/';
}
```

Try to confirm your custom `OnEnable` methods in the custom file "**CustomEntropireServer.java**" with whether the parameter has '/' or it follows the `[a-z0-9/._-]` rule.